# Is there a way to put indices in a proc sort?

Tags: sas

Suppose I sort a dataset as follows:

```
proc sort data = temp;
by type descending score;
run;
```

Is there an elegant way I can add a counter for each score within each type? I know I can use first and last statements but is there a way within the sort I add a counter?

```
TYPE SCORE   index
A   20        1      
A   10        2
A   5         3
B   90        1
B   80        2
B   70        3
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not such a way *within* a Proc Sort.  You need to either use a datastep, or a datastep view, to do such.

```
proc sort data = temp;
by type descending score;
run;

data temp_v / view=temp_v;
set temp;
by type descending score;
if first.type then counter=0;
if first.score then counter+1;
run;
```

That effectively does what you ask for - it adds a counter without adding an additional pass through the data.